# Is it generally recommended to use driver management software to update all obsolete drivers?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, updates

I installed driver management software (Driver Reviver) and I see dozens of drivers (PCI-E drivers etc.) that are obsolete/outdated. My system currently runs without any major issues and I feel like updating so many drivers could potentially result in issues, but perhaps result in better performance.

Is it generally recommended to use driver management software to update all obsolete drivers?

Comment: no, not it is not.

Comment: This is obviously an opinion-based question, but I can't bring myself to vote to close it because I can't imagine that any knowledgeable person would have a different opinion, and the opinion is fact-based.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the love of all all that is holy, remove that program immediately!

Most of these driver programs/websites are complete scams, injecting spyware and viruses.  Even the ones that arent scams, are just plain bad.  Just Googling it, shows Driver Reviver is "legitamate" but is known for installing older and the wrong drivers.

For the average user, there is no need to use any driver other than what Windows gives you.

If you really want to look for a newer driver, go to the *device manufacturer's website*.  There you will find compatible drivers for your hardware and OS, not some best guess from a piece of software.

Comment: Its also worth adding you don't *need* bleeding edge drivers all the time (I have one laptop with a touchpad that only works on an older driver), and a bulk update would mean if something goes wrong you don't know what caused it. Sometimes doing it by hand is always best.

Comment: Also, if win 7 didn't offer a driver update, more than likely the driver was up to date.