# Why does driver update software disagree with device manager?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, updates

On a whim, I installed IObit's driver updater. to my surprise. Instead of blindly following its suggestions, I used the device manager to update the drivers. Yet some updates that IObit's software listed were not found by device manager. Why is this?

Comment: Because IOBit is looking at multiple sources and Device Manager/Windows Update only looks at the driver the manufacture of the device submitted to Microsoft.  This is the reason using third-party software to manage your drivers is silly, and paying for such software is lame, using the certified version (unless it doesn't work) of the driver for the device is normally the best idea.  Only exception to this rule IMO is video display drivers, and only because, Nvidia and AMD continiously are making targeted software improvements to their drivers.  This is not the case with most device drivers.

Comment: [Is it generally recommended to use driver management software to update all obsolete drivers?](http://superuser.com/questions/1102560/is-it-generally-recommended-to-use-driver-management-software-to-update-all-obso?rq=1)

Comment: Interesting. What are these other sources? Could you clarify that and make it an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: My sources is entirely based on my experience over the last 2 decades.

Comment: All 3rd party driver updater's suck, they just do, 15 years experience experimenting with them. Driver updates offered by device manager (windows update) the the third best option, second best is the hardware manufacturers website, best is the PC manufacturers website,

Comment: @Ramhound. I mean the other sources that IOBit is looking at, not where you got the info. Also, please make it an answer so that I can mark it as correct.

Comment: I just know IOBit uses other sources, prolly it looks at OEM websites, among other sources

Comment: @Ramhound thank you so much for your clear answer and kindness, Please resubmit your response as an answer so that I can mark it as correct and solved.